# FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication on Android Device

Tags: android, sockets, exception, ftp-client

I am trying to upload an image captured by camera to FTP server, I am using FTPClient object, and it is working successfully when running the Java code on computer, but it fails when running the code on an android device.

I have checked the INTERNET permission, also internet connection is stable, also the other internet related functions are working correctly, only this ftp client is not working.

Here is the code:

```java
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.connect("ftp.mywebsite.com",21);
```

Please note that `mywebsite` is just a place holder.

It is throwing the following FTPConnectionClosedException exception

```
W/System.err: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:324)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:300)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:425)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:962)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:950)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:244)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:202)
W/System.err:     at com.basma.basma_rider.Helper$3.doInBackground(Helper.java:367)
W/System.err:     at com.basma.basma_rider.Helper$3.doInBackground(Helper.java:342)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```